# Sum of the integral of the $n$th power of the distribution function of real-valued random variable diverge

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ a real-valued random variable I need to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{F^{-1}((0,1))} F(s)^n d\mu(s) = \infty
$$
with $F$ the distribution function of $X$ and $\mu$ the law of $X$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What would be an obvious substitution to solve the integral?

Comment: I tried the Jensen inequality ($\int F^n \geq (\int F)^n$) but I think it's too weak. I also tried to consider $B_n:= F^{-1}([x_n;1))$ with $0<x_n<1$ in this way $\int F^n \geq \int_{B_n} x_n^n = \mu(B_n)x_n^n$ and try in some way to make it diverge but got no luck

Comment: About the substitution, the only thing that comes into my mind is to rewrite $F(s)^n=(\int_{-\infty}^s d\mu(t))^n$ but I don't see the point

Comment: Set $F(s) \to t$. Then, $\mathrm{d}\mu(s) = \mathrm{d}t$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Nope, I'm not too familiar with change of variable for measure on $\mathbb{R}$ different than the Lebesgue one

Answer (score 1):

Summing the geometric series (interchange of summation and integration okay by Tonelli) you're left to evaluate
$$
\int_{F^{-1}((0,1))}{1\over 1-F(s)}\,d\mu(s).
$$
This can be interpreted as an expectation:
$$
E\left[{1\over 1-F(X)}; 0<F(X)<1\right].
$$
If $F$ is continuous, you know that $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed over  $(0,1)$, and the end is in sight.

If $F$ has some jumps, the assertion is in doubt. For example, suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed over $\{1,2,\ldots,K\}$ for some positive integer $K$. Then the above expectation is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{K-1}{1\over 1-j/K}=\sum_{j=1}^{K-1}{K\over K-j}=K\sum_{i=1}^{K-1}{1\over i},
$$
which is finite.

Let $M:=\sup\{x: F(x)<1\}$. Evidently the expectation (hence the original sum) will be finite whenever $M<+\infty$ and  $F$ has a jump at $M$ but is constant in an interval $(M-\epsilon,M)$ just to the left of $M$.